# Как правильно писать "Е476" или "Е 476"?

Tags: орфография

Интересует правописание пищевых добавок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как правильно писать: "Е476" или "Е 476"?

‪Правильно – без пробелов: **Е476.‬**

‪Такое написание зафиксировано в ‬**ГОСТ 32770-2014 «Добавки пищевые.
ЭМУЛЬГАТОРЫ ПИЩЕВЫХ ПРОДУКТОВ.
Термины и определения»:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200113380

Answer (score 0):

На продуктах пишут без пробела. С пробелом не встречал.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_пищевых_добавок_E400_—_E499](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA_E400_%E2%80%94_E499)

Answer (score 0):

На грамоте.ру есть такой же вопрос http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=272712
Там в отчете указано, что дефис не нужен, и по-видимому пишется с пробелом.

Но вот на этом сайте первоначально код написан через дефис, но также указано, что существует три вариации кода: вместе, раздельно, и через дефис.
http://produkt-pitaniya.ru/dobavki-food
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]